# How to display an image within a loop?

Tags: php, html, mysqli

I am trying to retrieve data from a query result. Now what I am trying is that if a question has no images, then just output a blank, else if a question does have image(s), then output the image using an image tag. Only problem though is that it keeps outputting `Array`.

Where am I going wrong?

```
<?php foreach ($arrQuestionId as $key => $question) { ?>

    <div class='lt-container'>

        <p><?php echo htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionNo[$key]) . ": " . htmlspecialchars($arrQuestionContent[$key]); ?></p>

        <?php
//start:procedure image
        $img_result = '';
        if (empty($arrImageFile[$key])) {
            $img_result = '&nbsp;';
        } else {
            ?>

            <p>
                <img alt="<?php echo $arrImageFile[$key]; ?>" height="200" width="200" src="<?php echo $arrImageFile[$key]; ?>">
            </p>

            <?php
        }
//end:procedure image
        ?>

    </div>

<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Is $arrImageFile[$key] an array?  $arrImageFile[$key][0] give you the first image?

Comment: show array you are getting...

Comment: print_r($arrImageFile) will give you the structure of that array and echo according to that.

Comment: `var_dump($arrImageFile)` to check if it has what you expected.

Comment: Can you post $arrQuestionId structure?

Comment: The `var_dump($arrImageFile)` outputs this: `array(2) { [72]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(16) "Lighthouse_4.jpg" [1]=> string(12) "Tulips_3.jpg" } [73]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(16) "Hydrangeas_3.jpg" } } ` I have two questions which ids are 72 and 73

Comment: @Deadlock `var_dump($arrQuestionId)` gives you `array(2) { [72]=> int(72) [73]=> int(73) } `

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<p>
<?php foreach ($arrImageFile[$key] as $i) { ?>
    <img alt="<?= $i ?>" height="200" width="200" src="<?= 'ImageFiles/'.$i ?>">
<php } ?>
</p>
```

Comment: <? will work providing short_open_tags is enabled on your webserver.

Comment: Should I include the code where it checks if image is empty in foreach loop or don't do this?

Comment: You could just check if its empty and not run the loop if so.

Comment: So do what I am doing and put your code in the else statement, replacing the code currently in else statement

Comment: I tried your code by replacing what I had in else statement with your code but it does not display any images. It does remove the `Array` though

Comment: You don't do anything with $img_result so you could replace the whole if statement.  I don't know the contents of $arrImageFile so im just guessing, you may have to access the images with another key?  $arrImageFile[$key][$i]['image'] ?

Comment: If you look at comments below my question, 2nd from bottom, it shows output of a var_dump done for the $arrImageFile. A question may have no image or have one or multiple images. In var dump it shows question 1 has 2 images and question 2 having a image. Can you update your code to show full solution so I know how it should be implemented correctly?

Comment: Look at the source that my code produces.  It should have something like, <img alt="Lighthouse_4.jpg" height="200" width="200" src="Lighthouse_4.jpg"> 
Does that image exist on the root path?  or are they stored in a folder?

Comment: Images are stored in the `ImageFiles` folder. So it should be for example ImageFiles/Lighthouse_4.jpg`

Comment: Yeah thanks already got it. I needed an echo as I can't use short tag. Thanks for answer and help :)

Comment: It's bad practice to use short tags anyway, best just to avoid them.